# scrolling freezes and scroll not working in iphone devices ionic3?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have create the app in ionic3 it working perfectly but in the iphone devices scrolling not working and screen freezed.
if I use in the app.scss from this link:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11584

> .content-ios:not([no-bounce])>.scroll-content::before { bottom: 0; }

above css remove the bouncing effect but in the segment section screen are bouncing  again where we have to used segment section.after add above css scrolls perfectly with native momentum. But, div itself sometimes freezes and does not respond my finger moves. After 2-3 seconds later, it becomes again scrollable

I don't know how I am reproducing this problem. But, as I see there are two main behavior creates this situation.

First, If I wait for a while, for instance, 20 seconds, and touch the div, it does not respond. I wait a couple of seconds, and it becomes working again.

Second, I touch several times quickly, and then, it becomes freezing, and again, after a couple of seconds later, it starts working again.

How can I prevent this freezing as well scrolling
below we have create the video for that issue please check and let me know:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-0nyueulS4&feature=youtu.be

?

Comment: Put below css in the app.scss and its worked for me:                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                 
  ion-app.platform-ios12 ion-content { pointer-events: auto; /*fix scroll lock on ios12.2*/ }